# PHP prevent header overwriting by Proxy

Tags: apache, curl, proxy

I want to access a PHP script hosted on `dnsserver.icu` via this proxy `207.154.231.211:8080` with curl.

The problem is that the Proxy server seems to do overwrite the HTTP **200** code with a **302** code making it impossible to reach the script.

`curl -v dnsserver.icu` gives the following output:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: dnsserver.icu/
*   Trying 134.122.73.150...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to dnsserver.icu (134.122.73.150) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: dnsserver.icu
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2020 20:05:18 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
< Content-Length: 31
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
* Connection #0 to host dnsserver.icu left intact
```

whereas `curl -v -x 207.154.231.211:8080 dnsserver.icu` gives the unexpected result of:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: dnsserver.icu/
*   Trying 207.154.231.211...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 207.154.231.211 (207.154.231.211) port 8080 (#0)
> GET http://dnsserver.icu/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: dnsserver.icu
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: http://206.189.153.135
< Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2020 20:08:37 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host 207.154.231.211 left intact
```

The address in the Location header is also changing sometimes.

I already experimented with different header configurations but I couldn't get it to work. When I log every call to the PHP script it doesn't look like the server is even reached by the proxy (no call logged). Futhermore the apache access log is empty.

Strangely this is not the case for all domains. I'm able to access e.g. `ip-api.com`, `google.com` or also less popular domains like `proxyjudge.us` (but not the ip equivalent of 45.33.35.141) through the proxy.

I have no idea what the reason for this behaviour is. Is there any 'trick' in terms of header setting or apache configuration that makes it possible to also access `dnsserver.icu` through this proxy? Something I havent tought of?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: This proxy is not configured to proxy that site somehow.  It is configured to redirect.  302 is a redirect, so I expect that a RewriteRule is triggered in Apache, instead of a Proxy definition.

Comment: @Nic3500 But do you have an idea why proxying some sites is working while other sites return a 302?

Comment: Without seeing the Apache proxy configuration, impossible to say.